# Subsetting with dplyr and lubridate

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I need to determine how many persons are in a queue waiting for a call to the desk (think about a service: bank branch, post office etc.). I have data related to: date (year, month, day), arrival time for each person (year, month, day, hour, minute, second) and desk call time for each person (year, month, day, hour, minute, second).

My idea was: derive a subset thanks to dplyr and lubridate. I take a certain point of time (for instance 7.43 in a specific day) and take into account how many persons are waiting considering clients arrived and not called to the desk. My code was:

```
subset <- df %>%
  filter(day(Date) == 5 & arrival_time < "2017-06-05 07:43:00" & 
  call_time > "2017-06-05 07:43:00")
```

There are no errors (it works), but the results is zero, and I clearly see that this subset is not empty. what’s wrong with my code?
Many thanks

Comment: Impossible without seeing your data, but maybe: `arrival_time >` and `call_time <`?

Comment: If you're using `dplyr` you don't need to `and` like that.  Comma separation between the statements defaults to `and`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess: is the `Date`-column of class "POSIXct"? I.e. is it a date? Than you would need to filter it against a date, as well. With `lubridate` you can do that as follows:

```
library(lubridate)
subset <- df %>%
  filter(day(Date) == 5 & arrival_time < ymd_hms("2017-06-05 07:43:00") & 
    call_time > ymd_hms("2017-06-05 07:43:00"))
```